# using In memory database for laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

I intend to use in memory database for unit testing in laravel...
I added this lines to **phpunit.xml**,

```
<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite" />
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:" />
</php>
```

And this is my BookTest.php file inside \tests\Feature\BookTest.php directory,

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class BookTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function test_books_can_be_created()
    {        
        $user = factory(\App\User::class)->create();

        $book = $user->books()->create([
            'name' => 'The hobbit',
            'price' => 10
        ]);

        $found_book = $book->find(1);

        $this->assertEquals($found_book->name, 'The hobbit');
        $this->assertEquals($found_book->price, 10);


    }
}
```

But when we tried to add **vendor\bin\phpunit** I get,

> 1) Tests\Feature\BookTest::test_books_can_be_created
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: books (SQL: insert into "books" ("name",
>   "price", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (The hobbit,
>   10, 1, 2018-03-23 08:52:26, 2018-03-23 08:52:26))

it would be great help if you can help me on **how to use in memory database in laravel unit testing**.

Comment: Do you have a migration that creates that `books` table?

Comment: As I remember not. Do I need to have migrations too?. Really sorry if stupid

Comment: Yes you have ‘use databasemigrations’ that runs migrations

Answer (score 3):

You should

```
use RefreshDatabase
```

so your test should look like this

```
<?php

    namespace Tests\Feature;

    use Tests\TestCase;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

    class BookTest extends TestCase
    {
       use RefreshDatabase;

       public function test_books_can_be_created()
       {        
        $user = factory(\App\User::class)->create();

        $book = $user->books()->create([
            'name' => 'The hobbit',
            'price' => 10
        ]);

        $found_book = $book->find(1);

        $this->assertEquals($found_book->name, 'The hobbit');
        $this->assertEquals($found_book->price, 10);
    }
}
```

source https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: I have the same problem, and this is not the solutions here

Comment: What is the problem exactly?